# Function handle applied to array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've searched and there are many answers to this kind of question, suggesting functions like arrayfun, bsxfun, and so on. I haven't been able to resolve the issue due to dimension mismatches (and probably a fundamental misunderstanding as to how MATLAB treats anonymous function handles).

I have a generic function handle of more than one variable:

```
f = @(x,y) (some function of x, y)
```

Heuristically, I would like to define a new function handle like

```
g = @(x) sum(f(x,1:3))
```

More precisely, the following does exactly what I need, but is tedious to write out for larger arrays (say, 1:10 instead of 1:3):

```
g = @(x) f(x,1)+f(x,2)+f(x,3)
```

I tried something like

```
g = @(x) sum(arrayfun(@(y) f(x,y), 1:3))
```

but this does not work as soon as the size of x exceeds 1x1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it not an option to vectorize `f`, so that it also accepts array input for `y` and not just `x`? Otherwise what are the allowed dimensions of `x`?

Comment: The answer I gave is based on the limited information provided.  A better solution may be possible if you provide the implementation of `f` since it may be possible to vectorize the output in some manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change the definition of `f` to be more vector-friendly, you can use your last solution by specifying a [non-uniform output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html#namevaluepairs) and converting the output cell array to a matrix:

```
g = @(x) sum(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(y) f(x,y), 1:3,'UniformOutput',false)),2);
```

This should work well if `f(x,y)` outputs column vectors and you wish to sum them together.  For rows vectors, you can use

```
g = @(x) sum(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(y) f(x,y), 1:3,'UniformOutput',false).'));
```

If the arrays are higher in dimension, I actually think a function accumulator would be quicker and easier.  For example, consider the (extremely simple) function:

```
function acc = accumfun(f,y)
    acc = f(y(1));
    for k = 2:numel(y)
        acc = acc + f(y(k));
    end
end
```

Then, you can make the one-liner

```
g = @(x) accumfun(@(y) f(x,y),y);
```

Comment: I was just about to write almost the same:) However: does this work for any size of input for `x`? I was thinking along the lines of `C=arrayfun(@(y)f(x,y),1:3,'uniformoutput',false); sum(cat(length(size(x))+1,C{:}),length(size(x))+1)` for a general array of `x`, this should preserve the shape. But putting that into an anon function is messy.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The shape of `x` shouldn't matter; only the shape of `f(x,y)`.  And since the OP says that `f(x,1)+f(x,2)+f(x,3)` works, I assume the output array is regular enough that a one-liner could work ... we'll see.

Comment: `cell2mat` will concatenate the cell in 2d, right? While `f(x,1)+f(x,2)` will work for matrix-valued output. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You're right.  `cell2mat` smashes the arrays together which will not produce a proper sum for general arrays.  Rethinking.

Comment: Ooh, nice one with the accumulator:)

Comment: As always, this community has been wonderfully helpful. I apologise for the late response. The line

g = @(x) sum(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(y) f(x,y), 1:3,'UniformOutput',false).'));

worked perfectly. I use such accumulator function elsewhere, but thought there must be some way to get the result directly. Thanks again for all the comments, reading them was insightful.